# Check if all values of array are of the same type

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a good way to check if all items in an array are of the same type?

Something that does this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]  // true
[2, 3, 4, "foo"] // false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the types of each element in the array and make sure that it has at most one element:

```js
console.log( allSameType( [1,2,3,4] ) );
console.log( allSameType( [2,3,4,"foo"] ) );

function allSameType( arr ) {
  return new Set( arr.map( x => typeof x ) ).size <= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.every to check if all elements are strings.

```
arr.every( (val, i, arr) => typeof val === typeof arr[0]);

arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] // true  
arr = [1, "foo", true] // false
```

Note:

```
arr = [] // true
```

Comment: Well, because the question is missing any details about the environment, this answer could be valid, or not. When working with node, this would be okay. In Browsers I would not go with it.

Comment: @eisbehr why because a polyfill is too hard to implement?

Comment: @eisbehr Array.prototype.every works fine in most browsers, and if you really want to it work in IE8 it's very easy to shim it. My answer has much less browser support than this one, but can still work in an ES5 browser with something like babel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe less complicated solution would be

```
function sameTypes(arr, type) {
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (typeof item == type) {
            console.log('TRUE');
        } else {
            console.log('FALSE');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't go for this one. It's much longer than the other answers and you have to specify `type`, instead of just passing the array.

Comment: The answer is not about the length it is about readability here. I went for readable approach which is easily understandable and can be followed easily IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a functional approach using recursion.

```js
var array = [1, 2, "foo"]

function check([head, ...tail])
{
    if(!head)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        var flag = true
        tail.forEach(element => {
            flag &= typeof element === typeof head
        })
        return flag? check(tail) : false 
    }
}

console.log(check(array))
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a somewhat shorter solution, but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what OP asked but if you want to check if it's a certain type:

```js
function isArrayOfType(arr, type) {
  return arr.filter(i => typeof i === type).length === arr.length;
}

const numericArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const mixedArray = [1, 2, 3, "foo"];

console.log(isArrayOfType(numericArray, 'number')); // true
console.log(isArrayOfType(numericArray, 'string')); // false
console.log(isArrayOfType(mixedArray, 'number'));   // false
```